# Problem with CD DVD media Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, mount, dvd

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
first when I put CD with data Nautilus show me blank CD, the same CD on Windows 7 is read properly with data,
second I cant read DVD s
Even If somehow DVD is mounted I see blank space.
third I can`t write data on CD or on DVD.
Can any body help me with that ?
Xfbunr is not working
K3b is not working
Brasero is not working
Every program fails when comes to eject media.

Comment: I put normal CD with some data on it, and it is run properly.
DVD and DVD-R are also run well.
Seems something is wrong with CD-R media.
When I put CD-R with data on, Ubuntu see it like blink CD-R ready to write.
I check it on Ubuntu 12.04.02 live and on Ubuntu 13.04 live,  with the same result.
Any idea what could make these trouble ?

Answer (score 0):

I remember that nautilus had some trouble in beginning version
of 12.04 LTS - but it is fixed then in updates and in 12.04.02 LTS ?

You are new with ubuntu ? - then try this in konsole:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

if necessary then
sudo reboot

Comment: I am not new to ubuntu, I am using it sine 5 years. My curent ubuntu is fresh and updated installation.

Comment: [quote]Reading package lists... Done
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
[/quote]